# Magento 2: Plugin not working on \Magento\Swatches\Block\LayeredNavigation\RenderLayered

Tags: magento2, plugin, di

I'm trying to create a plugin for `\Magento\Swatches\Block\LayeredNavigation\RenderLayered` in order to modify the return of `getOptionViewData()`
**It's not working.**

My `di.xml` looks like that:

```
...

<type name="Magento\Swatches\Block\LayeredNavigation\RenderLayered">
    <plugin name="vendor_plugin_block_swatches_layerednavigation_renderlayered" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Swatches\LayeredNavigation\RenderLayered" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>

...
```

My plugin looks like that:

```
...

/**
 * @param \Magento\Swatches\Block\LayeredNavigation\RenderLayered $subject
 * @param callable $proceed
 * @param FilterItem $filterItem
 * @param Option $swatchOption
 * @return array
 */
public function aroundGetOptionViewData(
    \Magento\Swatches\Block\LayeredNavigation\RenderLayered $subject,
    callable $proceed,
    FilterItem $filterItem,
    Option $swatchOption
) {
    $data = $proceed($filterItem, $swatchOption);
    $data['test'] = 'working!';
    return $data;
}

...
```

I'm using Magento version 2.2.4

I don't want to override the entire class, I prefer to use a plugin.

Of course, I did `setup:di:compile`, `cache:flush`

Does anyone have the idea about this?

Comment: have did the di compile

Comment: of course I did that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quick answer is **No**. You can't use a plugin for a protected method, in this case: `getOptionViewData()`.

As the limitation on the DevDocs:

> Limitations Plugins cannot be used with any of the following:
>
> - Final methods
> - Final classes
> - Non-public methods
> - Static methods
> - `__construct`
> - Virtual types
> - Objects that are instantiated before Magento\Framework\Interception    is bootstrapped
> - Objects that are not instantiated by the ObjectManager (e.g. by using    new directly).

Reference https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

I suggest you write an after plugin for this method: `getSwatchData()` instead of `getOptionViewData()`.

Cheers.

Comment: I know that because I read the docs, but it did work for me in other cases to override protected methods. Also, just to make sure, I temporarily changed the original method to public & it still didn't work, so I believe that it's not the reason.

Comment: There is no way you can override a protected method without using the preferences. I don't think that you able to use a plugin with non-public methods. If you turn on the xdebug and see the trace, it will be very easy to understand why.

Comment: About the suggestion to override the getSwatchData() instead. Thanks! I'll do that.

Comment: @Pini `toHtml()` is a public method all the time and in any blocks my friend. But sometimes, there is `_toHtml()` as well, and that's protected method, they're quite similar...

Comment: Just noticed, I guess you are correct.